# How to access a Laravel site from another machine on the same network?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, webserver, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel site on my computer which I can access by typing the `php artisan serve` command. However I cannot access the site from another machine on the same network.

Is there a way to access the site from another machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is! There are two ways to go about it.

**Method 1: Passing a Host Parameter to Artisan**

First figure out your computer IP address. If you are on Linux or Mac, type `ifconfig` at the terminal. If you are on Windows, type `ipconfig` at the command prompt.

Then, go to your Laravel root directory and just type:

> `php artisan serve --host=XX.XX.XX.XX`

If you'd also like to pass the port parameter, just add `--port=XX` to the artisan serve command.

**Method 2: Serving via a Webserver (like Apache)**

Setup Laravel inside your Apache webserver directory through composer. Navigate to your laravel directory and set permissions of the storage folder to 777 by typing this command at the terminal: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`

Access your Laravel site by navigating to

> http://IPADDR/laravelproject/public

And voila!